# Google Hangouts Async load with Invites

Tags: google-hangouts

I'm using the async load option to run the Google Hangouts button, but I have no idea how/where to add the portion to add the invites.

> window.___gcfg = {
>         lang: 'pt-BR'
>       };
>       (function() {
>         var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
>         po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderButtons';
>         var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
>       })();

```
function renderButtons(){
  gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-div1', {
      'render': 'createhangout',
      'widget_size': 160
    })
}
```

I'll be adding this code in my web app.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of adding the 'invites' parameter to what you've got already.

```
function renderButtons(){
  gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-div1', {
      'render': 'createhangout',
      'widget_size': 160,
      'invites': [{ id : '1234', invite_type : 'PROFILE' }, { id : 'foo@example.com', invite_type : 'EMAIL' }]
    })
}
```